# Python - Element item Xpath with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm creating a bot to download a pdf from a website. I used selenium to open google chrome and I can open the website window but I select the Xpath of the first item in the grid, but the click to download the pdf does not occur. I believe I'm getting the wrong Xpath.

I leave the site I'm accessing and my code below. Could you tell me what am I doing wrong? Am I getting the correct Xpath? Thank you very much in advance.

This site is an open government data site from my country, Brazil, and for those trying to access from outside, maybe the IP is blocked, but the page would be this:

[Image site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQBNE.png)

[Source site](https://www.tce.ce.gov.br/cidadao/diario-oficial-eletronico)

Edit

[Page source code](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/fd6CE2L7#link)

```py
    import time
    
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    
    service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    
    navegador = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
    
    try:
        navegador.get("https://www.tce.ce.gov.br/cidadao/diario-oficial-eletronico")
        time.sleep(2)
    
        elem = navegador.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="formUltimasEdicoes:consultaAvancadaDataTable:0:j_idt101"]/input[1]')
        elem.click()
    
        time.sleep(2)
    
        navegador.close()
        navegador.quit()
    
    except:
        navegador.close()
        navegador.quit()
```

Comment: Website is getting blocked.

Comment: This site is an open government data site from my country, Brazil, I think because they are accessing from outside, through a VPN or TOR, the site blocks access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need this PDF, right?:

```html
<a class="maximenuck " href="https://www.tce.ce.gov.br/downloads/Jurisdicionado/CALENDARIO_DAS_OBRIGACOES_ESTADUAIS_2020_N.pdf" target="_blank"><span class="titreck">Estaduais</span></a>
```

You'll need to locate that element by xpath, and then download the pdf's using the "href" value `requests.get("Your_href_url")`

The XPATH in your source-code is `//*[@id="menu-principal"]/div[2]/ul/li[5]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[14]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[3]/a` but that might not always be the same.

Comment: This site is an open government data site from my country, Brazil, I think because they are accessing from outside, through a VPN or TOR, the site blocks access. I'll edit the question to try to be clearer.

Comment: For telling of you're xpath is correct, we'd either need the page source-code or acess to the website, and that's only possibe when you're in brazil, or with a unlisted proxy for brazil.

Comment: I edited the question where I put the page source file I got by CTRL-U. I hope it helps.

Comment: Just edited that answer, such that it might provide your answer. If yes, please "accept" the answer.

Comment: I managed to spot the error! It was the iframes of the page that masked the html and the xpath. Usei a função `browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)`